# awk to use header field to count fields

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to count the headers and use those as field numbers.  My problem is two fold:

The `awk` is close, but I need some expert help to make it better.  Thank you :).

1. the `awk` as is ignores the field headers and defines the fields using the text (sometimes field 5 starts with NM_, other times it is LRG_) as the RefSeqGene.txt illustrates.  I think that is because not all the fields have text, but what is consistent are the headers.
2. I only want to pull the row where `$10` = "reference standard"

**awk**

```
awk 'FNR==NR {E[$1]; next }$3 in E {print $3, $5}' panel_genes.txt     RefSeqGene.txt > update.txt
```

**example of panel genes.txt** (used to search RefSeqGene.txt)

```
ACTA2
BRAF
BHLHB9
```

**example of RefSeqGene.txt**

```
#tax_id GeneID  Symbol  RSG LRG RNA t   Protein p   Category
9606    59  ACTA2   NG_011541.1     NM_001613.2     NP_001604.1     reference standard
9606    59  ACTA2   NG_011541.1     NM_001141945.1      NP_001135417.1      reference standard
9606    673 BRAF    NG_007873.3 LRG_299 NM_004333.4 t1  NP_004324.2 p1  reference standard
9606    80823   BHLHB9  NG_021340.1     NM_001142524.1      NP_001135996.1      aligned
9606    80823   BHLHB9  NG_021340.1     NM_001142525.1      NP_001135997.1      aligned
9606    80823   BHLHB9  NG_021340.1     NM_001142526.1      NP_001135998.1      aligned
```

**desired output**

```
ACTA2     NM_001613.2   
ACTA2     NM_001141945.1
BRAF      NM_004333.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one-liner gives your the desired output:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}
     $(NF-1)$NF=="referencestandard" && $3 in a{print $3, ($5~/^NM_/?$5:$6)}' file1 file2
```

- `$(NF-1)$NF=="referencestandard"` checks your `$10`
- if `$5` begins with `NM_` we take it, otherwise, we take the `$6`

Comment: @EdMorton use the HP sauce to paste? btw, I did google HP sauce, I saw **HP**, and thought it could be a HP Unix specific tool.....:D